# Is Civibooking compatible with PHP 7?

Tags: civibooking

We depend on Civibooking and CiviCRM developers with be ending support for PHP 5X soon. What is the status of Civibooking and PHP 7? I did try to run on PHP 7 a while back and had issues in Civibooking.

Comment: Tish - did you test CiviBooking with PHP 7?  Did it work?  I need to allow members to book time with specific staff members.  Would rather not spend time on CiviBooking if it won't work with PHP 7 as that's what powers the rest of the site.  Thanks.

Comment: I upgraded to PHP 7 and CiviBooking worked fine. I had tried it out earlier and had issues with it. I think the developers updated it and I had forgotten that I had installed it. I am happy it is working as I wasn't looking forward to fixing it. I've looked under the hood of it, and saw that it was going to take me some time.

Comment: what CiviCRM version are you using? I tried it with Civi 5.9.1 and couldn't quite get it to work. [This](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civibooking) says it only supports up to 4.7.x so I know I'm pushing my luck!

Comment: I'm using Civi 5.9.1 and so far it is working fine. I am using the latest Drupal 7.63. I have to clear CiviCRM's caches "after" updates. If I don't, CiviBooking usually does something strange. I know that is too simplistic, but it's all I can think of to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try it out whether it works on PHP7. And if you find out it breaks you have two options:

1. Fix it yourself (if you are a developer) and push a *Pull request* to the original developer
2. The other option you have is that you pay a developer to fix CiviBooking.

There is also a third option and that is to ask around in the community whether there are other people willing to contribute to make CiviBooking compatible with PHP 7.

I have one last remark, PHP, CiviCRM are all open source. So there is no supplier who guarantees that stuff keeps working. The End of support of PHP5x does actually not mean a lot, it means that the original developers of php5 will not bring out any new (security) releases of that php version. But others might still do that and no one prevents you to fix your php yourself when you discover a security flaw.

One really last remark, you said you depend on CiviBooking. The other option you have is not to upgrade php 5 to 7 as it brings in a risk for continuity of your primary process in your organization. But if you do not upgrade you have another risk and that is that your php 5 might become insecure at some point in the future.

Comment: I am well aware that Civibooking is open source (free). That is why I am using it and the idea of paying somebody to fix it kinda flies in the face of the reason for using it. I wanted to know if the developers were going to update it and maybe add some new features, just for my information and future planning purposes. You are right that I could fix it. But, it would be nice if they did it for me and I could use my time elsewhere.

Comment: I totally agree, it is always nice if the original developers have plans to do update it.

Comment: Free to use - but developed because there were resources available at the time and likely not developed / maintained now because those resources are not there.